# VirtualScroll in Sidemenu

Tags: ionic3

I am new to Ionic 3 and am trying to use an `ion-list` with `VirtualScroll` in the sidemenu of the ionic-starter-template "sidemenu".

My **app.html** currently looks like this:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
 <ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar>
     <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
   </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>

 <ion-content>
   <ion-list [virtualScroll]="pages">
     <ion-item *virtualItem="let page">
       ....
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side 
menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Everything else is unchanged.

As soon as I user `[virtualScroll]` I am receiving:

```
ERROR Error: No provider for ViewController!
at injectionError (core.es5.js:1231)
at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1269)
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2770)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2809)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2741)
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2610)
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (core.es5.js:3578)
at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11039)
at createClass (core.es5.js:10903)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10723)
```

To my understanding `virtualScroll` needs a `ViewController` injected, but for some reason, this is not possible in the root component. It works fine on pages.

I know that you cannot inject a `Viewcontroller` into the root component, because they have a parent-child relationship. So how am I able to use `virtualScroll` lists in sidemenus?

Thanks in advance and please let me know if you need other parts of the code.